# Satellite TV on Ubuntu?

Tags: tv

I have an "old" Tv card from TechniSat, the SkyStar 2 TV. I bought it a few years ago but it never worked on windows.. so now I wanna reuse it, has somebody experience with TV on ubuntu? What software should i use?
Also i want to know what specs the computet should have for full HD recording...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to TRY TO use "[MythTV](https://www.mythtv.org/)" available for Ubuntu and easily installed directly from the GUI Ubuntu Software Center.

When I specify TRY TO, I'm referring to the fact that while it supports many popular TV tuner cards, it of course cannot support all of them.  In addition, there are some really nice such devices which have likely come so far from yours you may wish to invest in something different when you learn what all your options are.

I especially want to take the time to warn you not to be misled by the name into installing MythBuntu.  It is not what it sounds like.  it is not a package for Ubuntu, but rather it is an all in one pre-integrated tv/tuner/dvr package preinstalled into Ubuntu.  In some ways it is ideal for people who want everything to work without having to learn as much about Ubuntu, but if you are on this site, the odds are you don't need it.  Of course if you have a couple spare hard drives laying around you can switch between for best result, you can try both.  I tried five hard drives when I was first getting started.

A little more about MythTV.  It started out as a project to merely make a TV/DVR program for Linux because while many such cards existed, there simply wasn't such a thing as a tv card package for linux and that simply would not do.  The grandness of the scale of its features was never imagined at first, but with lots of interest, support and imagination it spread into one of the most fantastic programs I've ever read about.  It really deserves to be its own standalone operating system so I really understand why the mythbuntu version came into being.

Comment: @rudolf97, thank you for the rapid best answer.  I know you won't regret it, provided of course the program I suggested supports your card, but I'm amazed that it seems barley three minutes since I posted it before I noticed you'd given it best answer.

Comment: you are welcome. Well i will have to read into it. One question left.. i heard about ubuntu TV, is it ony for tv systems or can i also use it with a tv card in a normal computer?

Comment: @rudolf97 Your card is supported under Linux and MythTV. See http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Digital_Tuner_Cards and links there relative to your card. MythTV supports multiple tuner inputs, so if you have another card or capture device, it can also be used if it is on the supported hardware list.